# Unable to select SQL Spatial table line feature

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, sql-server, select, sql-server-spatial

I have a table in a SQL database that has been spatially enabled with a geography column.

In ArcGIS it is a line feature and can be viewed in ArcMap with no issues and even published as a map service with ArcGIS for Server.

However, neither the feature when it is in ArcMap or as a map service in a web app is able to be selected through the map. It can be selected through the attribute table.

I have adjusted and tested all selection settings in ArcMap. I have exported the data out as a shapefile an it works correctly. I have another table in the same SQL database that is a point feature and it works correctly.

Has anyone experienced this before or know of any esri bug related to this?

UPDATE 1:

I have rebuilt the table using geometry instead of geography - no change.

There is one feature that can be selected, it is the only feature west of the prime meridian.

UPDATE 2 (in response to comments):

1- Not sure about spatial indexes with SQL Spatial tables, please advise what i should be looking for?

2- I added the table to ArcMap from the database connection made in ArcCatalog, it calculated the extent on import, and maintained the correct spatial reference information as below:

> GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]

The data also draws in the correct locations.

3- The table does have an objectID field. The table is not in a geodatabase, it is in SQL Server.

UPDATE 3:

Have found the below known issue. Not exactly what I am experiencing but similar. I adjusted the data to only be inside one hemisphere and it is still not working.

[Bug: Spatial query fails...](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011211)

UPDATE 4:

Have tested the same data in Blue Marble Global Mapper, and it works correctly. Looking like an esri bug.

Comment: This sounds like it may be a spatial index problem. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify how you loaded the table, the exact spatial reference parameters used, and details about all column definitions.

Comment: Is the table registered with the geodatabase? Does the table have an objectid field? I don't think selections can be executed without it.

Comment: See updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was there were some stacked points in the data, in these cases x and y were the same between two points but the z values were different, hence drawing a vertical line. This is invalid geography in SQL Spatial.

The script was adjusted to select only distinct x and y values, effectively collapsing the stacked points into a single feature. This means that in a 3D world the line is incorrect, but on a 2D map it still appears correctly.